# tinder card slider flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use this package

https://github.com/buurzx/tinderCloneUI

I just have a question

why when I'm adding more than four profile objects it doesn't appear ?

for example here I'm adding more then four items of persons

```
    final List<Profile> demoProfiles = [
  new Profile(
    photos: [
      "assets/photo_1.jpg",
      "assets/photo_2.jpg",
      "assets/photo_3.jpg",
      "assets/photo_4.jpg",
    ],
    name: "Gross person",
    bio: "You better swpe left",
  ),
  new Profile(
    photos: [
      "assets/photo_2.jpg",
      "assets/photo_3.jpg",
      "assets/photo_4.jpg",
      "assets/photo_1.jpg",
    ],
    name: "Someone Special",
    bio: "This is the person you want",
  ),
  new Profile(
    photos: [
      "assets/photo_1.jpg",
      "assets/photo_2.jpg",
      "assets/photo_3.jpg",
      "assets/photo_4.jpg",
    ],
    name: "Gross person",
    bio: "You better swpe left",
  ),
  new Profile(
    photos: [
      "assets/photo_1.jpg",
      "assets/photo_2.jpg",
      "assets/photo_3.jpg",
      "assets/photo_4.jpg",
    ],
    name: "Gross person",
    bio: "You better swpe left",
  ),
  new Profile(
    photos: [
      "assets/photo_1.jpg",
      "assets/photo_2.jpg",
      "assets/photo_3.jpg",
      "assets/photo_4.jpg",
    ],
    name: "Gross person",
    bio: "You better swpe left",
  ),

];
```

but after the fourth person card go every thing disappear.

have any body used this package before can help me fix this issue please.

I think the problem is in this call

```
    widget.matchEngine.cycleMatch();
```

please if there is anybody familiar with flutter help me

Comment: did you try this library ... https://pub.dev/packages/tcard

Comment: yeah but it's not like tinder ,thank you I solve the issue @mohandesR